# Magento, cannot rewrite Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal

Tags: class, magento, url-rewriting, overriding

For one of my module I’m trying to rewrite the class Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal.
I used to rewrite models, no problem with that. I understand that the abstract classes cannot be rewritten.
But this one, I’m stuck ...

My aim is to rewrite protected function _initItem($address, $item), I have failed, and tryed to rewrite every function (with parent:: replacement by grandparent class). No more luck for me.

Here is my config :

```
<!-- in app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/etc/config.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<global>
    <models>
        <sales_quote>
            <rewrite>
                <address_total_subtotal>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</address_total_subtotal>
            </rewrite>
        </sales_quote>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

And my class :

```
# in app/code/local/Mynamespace/Mymodule/Model/Sales/Quote/Address/Total/Subtotal.php
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal extends Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal
{
protected function _initItem($address, $item)
{
    Mage::log("rewrite");
}
}
```

Can anyone help me with that ? Seems to be the same problem as an abstract class so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the model's alias you want to override is `sales`, not `sales_quote`. Try this:

```
    <models>
        <sales>
            <rewrite>
                <quote_address_total_subtotal>Mynamespace_Mymodule_Model_Sales_Quote_Address_Total_Subtotal</quote_address_total_subtotal>
            </rewrite>
        </sales>
    </models>
```

Comment: Ok that was my mistake ! Thank you very much, next time I will give an eye to the core config.xml associated to the class I want to rewrite. Thanks for your contribution.